# Run shell script with node.js (childProcess)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to run a shell script on my node.js server, but nothing happened...

```
childProcess.exec('~/./play.sh /media/external/' + req.params.movie, function() {}); //not working
```

Another childProcess works perfect, but the process above won't.

```
childProcess.exec('ls /media/external/', movieCallback); //works
```

If I run the script in terminal, then it works. Any ideas? (chmod +x is set)

Comment: Are there any [`'error'`s](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) or does it output any [`'data'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) to [`stdout`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout) or [`stderr`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stderr)?

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: /root/./play.sh: not found, How I have to modify my command to run this script stored in home dir?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The exec function callback has error, stdout and stderr arguments passed to it. See if they can help you diagnose the problem by spitting them out to the console:

```
exec('~/./play.sh /media/external/' + req.params.movie,
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: /root/./play.sh: not found, How I have to modify my command to run this script stored in home dir?

Comment: Thank you, found it out, it was just the incorrect path. (I think I have to go to bed (23:39 UTC+1))

Comment: is `exec('~/./play.sh /media/external/' + req.params.movie ...` a safe construct?

Answer (score 5):

```
exec('sh ~/play.sh /media/external/' + req.params.movie ,function(err,stdout,stderr){
      console.log(err,stdout,stderr);
 })
```

Runs your `play.sh` shellscript with `/media/external/`+req.params.movie as argument. The output is available through stdout,stderr variables in the callback.

**OR TRY THIS**

```
var myscript = exec('sh ~/play.sh /media/external/' + req.params.movie);
myscript.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data); // process output will be displayed here
});
myscript.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data); // process error output will be displayed here
});`
```

Comment: Please, add explanation to your answer