# Launch node script from bash script

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, shell

I've my program in bash and I want to launch a node program to get the string that it return, like in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring=$( node getString.js)
mplayer $mystring
```

Googling I found that I should inlcude

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

But I need to use string to give it to mplayer.. any ideas?

### Solution

As Zac suggesting (and thanks to **[this link](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs)**) I solved my problem in this way:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 

mplayer ${1}
```

**script.js**

```
/* do whatever you need */
var output="string"
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout);  }
exec("./script.sh " + output, puts);
```

Comment: Side note: please quote your BASH variables, like so: `mplayer "$mystring"`

Answer (score 1):

Consider simply writing an executable Node script (with the `#!/bin/env node` line), and, instead of using Bash, just use Node to run the external UNIX command. You can use the [child_process module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for this, as illustrated in [this example](http://jlunaquiroga.blogspot.com/2014/03/creating-processes-in-nodejs.html). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess) is also helpful when debugging shell-style subcommands in Node scripts.

If your example really is all you need to do in Bash, this should be sufficient. The `#!/bin/env node` line allows your script, once marked as executable, to run as its own program, without having to be invoked with `node`.