# Execute an shell program with node.js and pass node variable to the shell command

Tags: node.js, shell, parameters

I would like to pass variable from node to shell command and execute it from node.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

To execute shell commands:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('command', function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

From: [Run shell script with node.js (childProcess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess),

To run a program bar.sh in your home folder with the argument 'foo':

```
var foo = 'foo';

exec('~/bar.sh ' + foo,
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Now, how can I read this param in my .sh please

Comment: Arguments can be accessed in shell scripts with $X --- where X is the order the argument was passed.
If your script bar.sh contains 
´echo first param: $1, second param:$2´
It will print "first param: foo, second param:baz" 
when running ´sh bar.sh foo baz´

More info [here](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html)

Comment: **This has major security vulnerabilities** if `foo` comes from a request or other source that untrusted users can control -- think about `foo='$(rm -rf ~)'`. The safe way to do it is to use `execFile()` with `foo` passed in the `args` list. That is, `execFile("/path/to/bar.sh", [foo], function(error, stdout, stderr) { ... });`

Comment: DO NOT FOLLOW THIS ANSWER. IT ALLOWS FOR SHELL SHOCK VULNERABILITY

Comment: @ShawnShroyer it's always more helpful to provide an alternative solution so others can learn. "Don't do XYZ" and not providing a viable alternative doesn't help newbies