# Execute Shell Script in JavaScript IF Clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

Hi everybody a simple question but i do not find the answer for it.
I want execute a shell file when the condition in my if clause is true
I tried it with that sniplet:

```
if ( state === true) 
{
   console.log("Hello");
   sudo ./test.sh
}
```

Could someone please explain how to solve it in a simple way?

Comment: Javascript is not going to do that, if it is nodejs, search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from the question, I think you are trying to write server-side JavaScript code to execute a shell script.

As @epascarello mentioned, you can use NodeJS exec() function as under:

```
exec('sh sudo ./test.sh', function(error, stdout, stderr){
      console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
})
```

For more information please refer to this thread: [Run shell script with node.js (childProcess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess)

Comment: ok..  it is working when i am executing it via the console. but if i add this in my if clause the response from the console is an error command not found.

Comment: when you say that it is working "via the console", do you mean the Unix shell or javascript console?
Also, try using the absolute path to your shell script.

Comment: hoi, thanks i solved it and added the full patch..  thanks. the absolute patch was the solution