# Escape to shell from TestCafe script

Tags: javascript, bash, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am working on a TestCafe script where I capture an endpoint URL that needs to serve as an input for a shell/bash command.

```
const inputText = await Selector('textarea[name="url-input"]').value;
console.info(`This is my URL of interest ${inputText}`)
```

Then I want to use `inputText` to execute a bash command, say (for simplicity)

```sh
echo inputText
```

How can this be accomplished from my testcafe script? I couldn't find a related post of documentation on this.

I did find a related post on Javascript that uses `process.createChildProcess('command');`, but I'm still trying to make this solution work. See docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
// on declarations
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// inside the test
exec('echo "The \\$HOME variable is $HOME"');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with the following, from [this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript) and [this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess).

```
// on declarations
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// inside the test
const inputText = await Selector('textarea[name="url-input"]').value;
exec(inputText,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
        console.error('exec error: ' + error);
      }
    });
```